# AChartEngine renders null values

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I have a BarChart which has some values which are set to MathHelper.NULL_VALUE so they are not rendered (it is supposed to leave blank positions in the chart). However, the null values are still rendered and look more like 0.0 as shown below.

[image: null values]

If I log the values printed I can see that the NULL_VALUEs are present in the series:

```
10-23 09:50:24.206: DEBUG/ConsumptionChartBuilder(27359): x:16.0Y:1.0
10-23 09:50:24.206: DEBUG/ConsumptionChartBuilder(27359): x:17.0Y:3.0
10-23 09:50:24.206: DEBUG/ConsumptionChartBuilder(27359): x:18.0Y:1.7976931348623157E308
10-23 09:50:24.206: DEBUG/ConsumptionChartBuilder(27359): x:19.0Y:1.7976931348623157E308
10-23 09:50:24.216: DEBUG/ConsumptionChartBuilder(27359): x:20.0Y:6.0
10-23 09:50:24.216: DEBUG/ConsumptionChartBuilder(27359): x:21.0Y:1.7976931348623157E308
```

Setting/Unsetting the min Y value doesn't change anything.

I really need to differentiate between 0 and null and leaving points out of the bar chart results in some further odd rendering (the blank spaces are not the correct width)...

**Does anyone know how to not render null values in an AChartEngine BarChart?**

Edit: Some code which reproduces it.

```
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset multipleSeriesDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multipleSeriesRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer= new XYSeriesRenderer();

    //set up renderer(s)
    renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    multipleSeriesRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 3, 0, 0});
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    //text size
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setLabelsTextSize((int)(scale*10+0.5f));

    multipleSeriesRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    //set max and min of axis
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setYAxisMax(10);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setXAxisMax(7.5);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.1);

    //set up series
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("test");
    series.add(1, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE);
    series.add(2, 1);
    series.add(3, 6);
    series.add(4, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE);
    series.add(5, 0);
    series.add(6, 5);
    series.add(7, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE);
    multipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(series);

    //add x labels to replicate my original code
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Mon");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Tue");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Wed");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Thu");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Fri");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Sat");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Sun");

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_graph)).addView(ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, multipleSeriesDataset, multipleSeriesRenderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT));
```

**Edit number 2: Screenshots of the above code:**

With null values:

[image: screenshot with null values]

If I don't add the null values then the graph looks skewed as shown here where the bars touch one another.

[image: screenshot without null values]

Comment: Show us some code, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: Please note that the code you added displays something while the screenshot shows something else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't add the `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE` values. Just add the other ones.

Comment: Thanks for the interest Dan! Really love AChartEngine! I added screenshots of what the sample code produces with and without nulls.

Comment: Cool. So it looks like that fixed the issue you had?

Comment: sorry nope. See how the bars now have no gaps between them and the width of the space where the missing points should be is quite a bit different to that with null values?

Comment: In this case, you will have to checkout the ACE code and update BarChart.java to work the way you need. The current behavior is caused by previous users request.

Answer (score 0):

I Think ur intention is to make those  MathHelper.NULL_VALUE bars as blank so u can set those bar color.transparent so they will not visible if ur intention is wt i stated.so if u want to shows those bars u can put the values as {} blank.

Comment: hello ..this is possible for line chart?I use this but just getting point there not see line between this point.so any idea